# How to change layout dynamically in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have a grid with fluid layout. It has one component, a table, in a `span12` div - using the entire screen.

When a row in this table is clicked, I want to change the layout. I want to change the table's div to `span4` and create a new `span8` column on the right to display details of the selected item.

How can I do this programmatically? Something as simple as:

```
$("#mydiv").removeClass("span12").addClass("span4")
```

... doesn't seem to work, I believe I need to somehow tell Bootstrap to re-process the entire layout. Is it possible at all?

Comment: You don't need to reprocess anything, it's all CSS so it will apply the styles the moment you modify the. Most likely it's your JS or HTML at fault. Post those here.

Comment: JohnP is absolutely right. I created a JSFiddle to show that your code works well -> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HqQxz/).

Comment: John - this indeed was the case, thank you! Feel free to post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution:

```
var $table = $('.table-container'), // table inside
    $side  = $('.side-container');  // hidden by default
$table.on('click', 'tr', function() {
   $table.removeClass('span8').addClass('span4');
   $side.show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/meV43/

*I used total width of span8 in this demo*

With toggle column functionality http://jsfiddle.net/meV43/1/